# WatchKit: Change only one Interface Controller title color

Tags: swift, interface-builder, watchkit

Right now I only know one way to change the title color for an interface controller and it is changing it with global tint in storyboard.

[image]

However, this changes ever interface title color. How do I change just one interface controller title color? Any suggestions or tips is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do it programmatically at this time. So, it means that you can not change it on run time.

Whatever you can do, you can find the answer on the **Watch App Programming Guide**. We have to admit that there are so many limitations on this WatchKit version.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/

Comment: Dang, that really sucks. Hopefully Apple fixes this in the near future.

Comment: We believe they will, perhaps they are stilling testing the market. lol